# curl when writing to file named 'hosts' :Failed to create the file hosts: Permission denied

Tags: linux, curl

When I download a file with `curl` and **name it to `hosts`** with the command:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/racaljk/hosts/master/hosts -#o hosts
```

Then it will complain:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file hosts: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1929)
```

But when I **change the argument `-o hosts` to `-o hosts.rmt`**:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/racaljk/hosts/master/hosts -#o hosts.rmt
```

It will be OK.
And I have done some google searching about the problem, but I can't find the same problem.

Comment: What directory are you working in, and what are the permissions of this directory, and which user are you doing this as?

Comment: @cutrightjm, the directory is `/tmp/test`, and the permissions is `drwxrwxr-x 12 zhenguoli zhenguoli 16384 May 18 23:15 ./`, and the user me information is `uid=1001(zhenguoli) gid=1001(zhenguoli) groups=1001(zhenguoli),0(root),27(sudo),129(vboxusers),999(docker)`.

Comment: @cutrightjm, some sites have been blocked by the gfw, so i need to change  the hosts.

Comment: it seems a permissions problem of your system, I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: I have changed the directory to `777` which is `drwxrwxrwx 12 zhenguoli zhenguoli 16384 May 18 23:15 ./`, but it also complains the error.@cutrightjm

Comment: It seems you already have a file named `hosts` in your directory

Comment: @roaima, yes there is already one, but why when it named to other filenames, it will be ok, but it will fail on filename `hosts`?

Comment: Try `wget`, or `curl` this url instead (it's a copy+paste of the hosts list): https://pastebin.com/raw/Zqhzfbi8

Comment: I found it works now, but it's not working before has bothered me. Thanks. @cutrightjm.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/?domain=raw.githubusercontent.com) raw.githubusercontent.com doesn't have an IP associated with it, but it does for me in the states. Try to `curl` the URL from [this pastebin copy](https://pastebin.com/raw/Zqhzfbi8) of the hosts file.

Comment: Does it mean that curl can't obtain the consistent IP address, so it fails?

Comment: I am not sure exactly, but it sounds to me like gfw is actively trying to block connections from that domain.